# How to increase the height of iframe from which you application is being called?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, iframe

I have a React-On-Rails application which is being rendered inside a  of some other application and i don't have access to parent components code.

I want to change the height of the parent iframe from my react application.
How to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function in parent page:

```
var setHeight = function(height){
    setIframeHeight(height)   
}
```

Then,in child page,you can do like this:

```
parent.setHeight(200)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But i don't have access tot he parent code and i have to achieve it only though child component.
Is there a way to access the parent dom from child ?

Comment: No way to access the parent dom from child directly, it's not safe for parent page, parent page do not allow.